# Explain some python code. Accessing columns, which don't exist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The source of the code is here: https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/blob/master/zipline/examples/pairtrade.py

The chunk of code is this:

```
def ols_transform(data, sid1, sid2):
   """Computes regression coefficient (slope and intercept)
   via Ordinary Least Squares between two SIDs.
   """
   p0 = data.price[sid1]
   p1 = sm.add_constant(data.price[sid2], prepend=True)
   slope, intercept = sm.OLS(p0, p1).fit().params

   return slope, intercept
```

The data frame "data" is created from this:

```
data = load_from_yahoo(stocks=['PEP', 'KO'], indexes={},
                           start=start, end=end)
```

And has output like this:

```
                          PEP     KO
Date                                   
2001-01-02 00:00:00+00:00  15.25   9.20
2001-01-03 00:00:00+00:00  16.19   9.54
2001-01-04 00:00:00+00:00  16.55   9.72
2001-01-05 00:00:00+00:00  16.29   9.67
2001-01-08 00:00:00+00:00  16.09   9.79
2001-01-09 00:00:00+00:00  15.74   9.70
2001-01-10 00:00:00+00:00  15.74   9.61
2001-01-11 00:00:00+00:00  15.80   9.88
```

My problem is, how does this work?

```
   p0 = data.price[sid1]:
   p1 = sm.add_constant(data.price[sid2], prepend=True)
```

In the final block of code, 'price' is not defined as a column. I'm unsure why it can be called? It is not even the name of the data frame.

Is it something to do with the imported packages? Or am I missing something completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the previous line of the function (@batchtransform): https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/blob/master/zipline/examples/pairtrade.py#L28 which does some magic. For a more complete description of how this works, see the Quantopian help docs https://www.quantopian.com/help under "Batch Transforms."

However, note that this is an old example that be refactored to use the newer history() which achieves the same but faster and cleaner. The help docs also contain description of that.